# Difference between these pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, declaration, implicit-conversion

I wrote this C code

```
int A[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
int *P[3] = A;
```

which gives an error. However when I modify the pointer like this

```
int (*P)[3] = A;
```

The code compiles. What is the difference between these two pointers

Comment: And **what error** does it give?

Comment: `int *P[3]` is not a pointer, it's an array of pointers. You cannot assign an array to another array regardless of their types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration

```
int *P[3]
```

does not declare a pointer. It declares an array of three elements of the type `int *`.

You may even rewrite this declaration of the array the following way

```
int * ( P[3] )
```

However you may not initialize one array with another array even of the same type except that you may initialize character arrays with string literals.

This declaration

```
int (*P)[3]
```

indeed declares a pointer to an object of the array type `int[3]`. On the other hand the initializer used in this declaration

```
int (*P)[3] = A;
```

and that has the type `int[2][3]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[3]` (that is to the array `{1, 2, 3}`). So the declared object and the initializing expression have the same type `int ( * )[3]`.